# Creating Javascript or Jquery Date Array From a Start and an End Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, date

I am trying to create an in-page div that will take a start date, an end date, and a few other input fields and have it generate pre-formatted text for every 90 days within that time range. I have played around with using moment.js to make the date manipulation a little easier. This all needs to be included within one page.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>  </title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <label for="startDate">Start Date: </label>
    <input type="Date" value="" id="startDate" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label for="endDate">End Date: </label>
    <input type="Date" value="" id="endDate" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label for="radio">Radio Value: </label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" id="radio" />
    <br/>
    <label for="radio">Radio Value: </label>
    <input type="radio" value="2" id="radio" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label for="region1">Type State or Country: </label>
    <input type="text" list="regionList1" id="region1"  />
    <datalist id="regionList1">
    <option value="AS">All States</option>
    <option value="AK">All Countries</option>
    </datalist>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label for="region2">Type State or Country: </label>
    <input type="text" list="regionList2" id="region2"  />
    <datalist id="regionList2">
    <option value="AS">All States</option>
    <option value="AK">All Countries</option>
    </datalist>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label for="region3">Type State or Country: </label>
    <input type="text" list="regionList3" id="region3"  />
    <datalist id="regionList3">
    <option value="AS">All States</option>
    <option value="AK">All Countries</option>
    </datalist>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label for="region4">Type State or Country: </label>
    <input type="text" list="regionList4" id="region4"  />
    <datalist id="regionList4">
    <option value="AS">All States</option>
    <option value="AK">All Countries</option>
    </datalist>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label for="region5">Type State or Country: </label>
    <input type="text" list="regionList5" id="region5"  />
    <datalist id="regionList5">
    <option value="AS">All States</option>
    <option value="AK">All Countries</option>
    </datalist>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label for="phone">Phone: </label>
    <input type="phone" id="phone" placeholder="999-999-9999" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button type="submit" id="test" onClick="">SUBMIT</button> 
    <button type="reset" onClick="window.location.reload()">RESET</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="result"> 
    <!-- 
    This is where the program will generate a <div> tag, it should have:
    <div>
    Start Date <br/>
    (Start Date + 90 Days) <br/>
    Some Standard Text for Every Div Entry
    Radio Value <br/>
    Region1 - 5
    Phone Value <br/>
    Region1 Value <br/>
    Region2 Value <br/>
    Region3 Value <br/>
    Region4 Value <br/>
    Region5 Value <br/>
    </div>
    And This Div Should Be Repeated for Each 90 Day Date Range, Including Start and End Dates
    -->
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now, I have tried this a couple times and have a couple partial solutions, but since I have searched and searched on this and can't find an adequate solution, I wanted to ask the community how they would code for what I am asking for. I am just having a hard time wrapping my head around this for some reason. I get it to have a start date and show the additional 90 day block, but when I get to the end date, it won't add that to the last div block. I have a bunch of files made up, trying to work on this logic, so just copying and pasting the code won't make any sense. I am feeling really thick-headed for not coming up with an answer.

I am open to pure javascript or jquery solutions. I really appreciate any pointers that can be given to get this to work for me.

**EDIT**

Thank you to everyone that helped with this. I have come up with a solution with the help of Rocky, from below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>  
</title>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js">
</script>
<style>
  #result {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:1px;
    padding:3px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<label for="startDate">Start Date: </label>
<input type="Date" value="" id="startDate" />
<br/>
<br/>
<label for="endDate">End Date: </label>
<input type="Date" value="" id="endDate" />
<br/>
<br/>
<label for="radio">Radio Value: </label>
<input type="radio" value="i" id="radio" name="radio" />
<br/>
<label for="radio">Radio Value: </label>
<input type="radio" value="d" id="radio" name="radio" />
<br/>
<br/>
<label for="region1">Type State or Country: </label>
<input type="text" list="regionList1" id="region1"  />
<datalist id="regionList1">
<option value="AS">All States</option>
<option value="AK">All Countries</option>
</datalist>
<br/>
<br/>
<label for="region2">Type State or Country: </label>
<input type="text" list="regionList2" id="region2"  />
<datalist id="regionList2">
<option value="AS">All States</option>
<option value="AK">All Countries</option>
</datalist>
<br/>
<br/>
<label for="region3">Type State or Country: </label>
<input type="text" list="regionList3" id="region3"  />
<datalist id="regionList3">
<option value="AS">All States</option>
<option value="AK">All Countries</option>
</datalist>
<br/>
<br/>
<label for="region4">Type State or Country: </label>
<input type="text" list="regionList4" id="region4"  />
<datalist id="regionList4">
<option value="AS">All States</option>
<option value="AK">All Countries</option>
</datalist>
<br/>
<br/>
<label for="region5">Type State or Country: </label>
<input type="text" list="regionList5" id="region5"  />
<datalist id="regionList5">
<option value="AS">All States</option>
<option value="AK">All Countries</option>
</datalist>
<br/>
<br/>
<label for="phone">Phone: </label>
<input type="phone" id="phone" placeholder="999-999-9999" />
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="submit" id="test" onClick="">SUBMIT</button> 
<button type="reset" onClick="window.location.reload()">RESET</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="result"> 
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
$('#test').click(function() {
var region1 = $('#region1').val();
var region2 = $('#region2').val();
var region3 = $('#region3').val();
var region4 = $('#region4').val();
var region5 = $('#region5').val();

var radio = $('input[name=radio]:checked').val();

var phone = $('#phone').val();

const startDate = moment($('#startDate').val());
const endDate = moment($('#endDate').val());

const dateRanges = buildDateRanges(startDate, endDate);

//build result html
var result = '';
dateRanges.forEach(function(dateRange) {
  var html = '';
  html += '<div id="result">';
  html +=   'start: ' + dateRange.start.format('Y-M-D') + '<br/>';
  html +=   'end: ' + dateRange.end.format('Y-M-D') + '<br/>';
  html +=   'radio: ' + radio + '<br/>';
  html +=   'regions: ' + region1 + ", " +  region2 + ", " + region3 + ", " 
  + region4 + ", " + region5 +'<br/>';
  html +=   'phone: ' + phone + '<br/>';
  html +=   'region1: ' + region1 + '<br/>';
  html +=   'region2: ' + region2 + '<br/>';
  html +=   'region3: ' + region3 + '<br/>';
  html +=   'region4: ' + region4 + '<br/>';
  html +=   'region5: ' + region5 + '<br/>';
  html += '</div>';
  result += html;
});

$('#result').html(result);
});

function buildDateRanges(startDate, endDate) {
const dateRanges = [];

var curDate = moment(startDate);
while (curDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate)) {
  const range = {
    start: moment(curDate),
    end: moment(curDate).add(90, 'days')
  };
  if (range.end.isAfter(endDate)) range.end = endDate;

  dateRanges.push(range);

  curDate = moment(range.end).add(1, 'd');
}

return dateRanges;
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so if start date is 2017-01-01, end date is 2017-08-01, you want to generate three divs, first div includes start date=2017-01-01 and block date=2017-04-01,;second div includes start date=2017-04-01 and block date=2017-07-01; thir div includes start date=2017-07-01 and end date=2017-08-01?

Comment: Very Close, Yes. I want to have 2018-01-01 to 2018-04-01 and then have the next block pick up from the next day: 2018-04-02 to 2018-07-02. And then I want the next block to repeat the behavior all the way up to the end date. For the very last div, if the time is less than 90 days, that is fine. In the above example, that would be 2018-07-03 to 2018-08-01.

Comment: So you have a start and end date. Just keep adding 90 days until the start date is passed the initial end date. What, precisely, are you having trouble with? As it is, you're just asking for general advice which is off topic here.

Comment: I apologize if I am off topic. I have searched and searched to find an answer to this question. I feel that I was missing a component of this and I know this community to be great at coming up with solutions. I will watch this and be better about posting off-topic questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I would write to do a simplified version of what you have described. Hope it helps.

```
$(function() {
  $('#test').click(function() {
    const startDate = moment($('#startDate').val());
    const endDate = moment($('#endDate').val());

    const dateRanges = buildDateRanges(startDate, endDate);

    //build result html
    var result = '';
    dateRanges.forEach(function(dateRange) {
      var html = '';
      html += '<div>';
      html +=   'start: ' + dateRange.start.format('Y-M-D') + '<br/>';
      html +=   'end: ' + dateRange.end.format('Y-M-D') + '<br/>';
      html += '</div>';
      result += html;
    });

    $('#result').html(result);
  });

  function buildDateRanges(startDate, endDate) {
    const dateRanges = [];

    var curDate = moment(startDate);
    while (curDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate)) {
      const range = {
        start: moment(curDate),
        end: moment(curDate).add(3, 'M')
      };
      if (range.end.isAfter(endDate)) range.end = endDate;

      dateRanges.push(range);

      curDate = moment(range.end).add(1, 'd');
    }

    return dateRanges;
  }
});
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I need, but stripped down. I can always add the values from those other input fields, so that is fine. The problem that seems to show up in here is the same as I was encountering. For the last div in the result block, it isn't actually showing the actual end date. It is showing a date 90 days from the temporary start date in that very last div.

Comment: Are you sure you tried my latest version? That should be fixed by the `if (range.end.isAfter(endDate)) range.end = endDate;` line.

Comment: @T.Olver does it still not work correctly with the `if (range.end.isAfter(endDate)) range.end = endDate;` line in place?

Comment: Oh, I see that it is updated. Now, this code works mostly, but adding the 3 months to the end date doesn't always get 90 days, so after changing `moment(curDate).add(3, 'M')` to `moment(curDate).add(90, 'days')`, I think it works! I am going to  check it out and make sure that it works fully and if it does, I will upvote and mark as an answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: I tested it and after just a couple small and easy changes, it seems to be working. Obviously, I added the other input elements into this and changed some of the information. The datalist is a collection of the 2 digit state codes and 2 digit iso country codes and the radio buttons and things were also edited, but it works exactly how I needed it to. I was having an extremely hard time and trying to do an overly complex solution to a problem that didn't need it. Thanks, Rocky!

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help.